# Rails 4 Strong parameters with JSON array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to post an array of JSON objects, but i always get a 422 Unprocessable Entity response.
This is my controller action:

```
def create
 @myusers = params[:user]
 @myusers.each do
 User.create(user_params)
end     

def user_params
             params.permit(:name,:address )
end
```

Where,together with the below shown http call, the `@myuser` array looks like this

```
@myuser =[{"name"=>"name11", "address"=>"addr1"}, {"name"=>"name22", "address"=>"addr2"}, {"name"=>"name33", "address"=>"addr132"}, {"name"=>"name4", "address"=>"addr4"}]
```

This is the HTTP JSON body

```
{"user":[{
   "name" : "name11",
   "address":"addr1"
},
{
    "name" : "name22",
    "address":"addr2"
},
{
    "name" : "name33",
    "address":"addr132"
},
{
    "name" : "name4",
    "address":"addr4"
}
]}
```

and i added the `Accept/Content-Type : application/json` header.
The log file shows this

```
Started POST "/api/customer/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-02 18:45:09 +0100
Processing by Api::UserController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"user"=>[{"name"=>"name11", "address"=>"addr1"},  {"name"=>"name22", "address"=>"addr2"}, {"name"=>"name33", "address"=>"addr132"}, {"name"=>"name4", "address"=>"addr4"}]}
Unpermitted parameters: customer, format
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Unpermitted parameters: customer, format
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Unpermitted parameters: customer, format
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
Unpermitted parameters: customer, format
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Unpermitted parameters: customer, format
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 62ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

Each of the single objects is an `ApplicationControllerParameter` so it should be possible to call directly the `user_params` action for each entry? Or am i wrong there?

thanks in advance for your help.

**Solution:**

I think there s some possibility that this code can be done a bit more nice but this is now working for me:

```
  def user_params
         params.permit(user: [:name,:address])
  end

  def create 
         user_params[:user].each do |u|
             User.create(u)
         end
  end
```

Comment: Where did the `customer` and `format` params come from?

Comment: I think the customer param is the main json key which is then the array of hashes, I always get the unpermitted format parameter for reasons  i dont know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue as far as the question about parameters is concerned is that you're using the whole params hash and not narrowing it down to the 'user' bit that you're interested in permitting. So you're getting all the other stuff that's passed e.g. format. (Incidentally, shouldn't it more correctly be called 'users' rather than the singular 'user'? Anyway... Never mind that :)

I think it should be something like

```
params.permit(user: [:name, :address])
```

or

```
params.require(:user).permit?([:name, :address])
```

There's a bit about nested parameters in the docs of the strong_parameters gem here:

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters

Hope that helps...

Comment: Hey thanks for the link. This line which shows the coded nested parameter is really helpful. But i cannot get it to work. With your second statement the method permit is not defined on arrays and the first one return the complete array with the top `users` key. I also tried params.permit(:customer =>[:name, :address]) but without success

Comment: no ok now i got it :) the first line of code works. Since the key is an array, and the value(the array) contains  hashes i needed to iterate differently :) uufff

Answer (score -1):

So, you have an array of hashes coming through params, which needed to be permitted, and then you do a simple loop over your array to save each to your database.

The first step is getting the params permission right.

You can [check the documentation here for more insight into permitting params.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)

Let's define the users_params private method as follow:

```
def users_params
  params.permit(user: []) #declare that the parameter should be an array of permitted scalars by mapping it to an empty array
end
```

Then from the `create` action:

```
def create
  @myusers = users_params #this returns an array of the user hashes passed from params
  # Now, loop through these hashes, and create new users with their values
  @myusers.each do |user_hash| 
    User.create(user_hash)
  end
end
```

Note that we are not repeatedly going to fetch the JSON hashes from the params. Since we already have it all in our `@myusers` variable, all that is needed to do is to loop through it, and save a new instance of User with the hash at the current index of our loop.

More examples on how to permit different types of params are available in [the above documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit), you can check it out as well.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: Hi. tahnks for the answer but you solution is not working for me. The `@myuser` is always nil. I got it to work while `@myuser` params[:user] but i am unable to store the `user_hash` directly. I need to call to_hash before otherwise i get the forbittenattributes error