# How to alter params method to accept a JSON array in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic API built by `rails new my_api --api`, then `rails g scaffold model name age`.

I would like to alter the `model_params` method to accept a JSON array. How can I do this?

The current method is the default:

```rb
   def model_params
      params.require(:model).permit(:name, :age)
   end
```

#### What I've tried

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484145/rails-4-strong-parameters-with-json-array):

```rb
    def model_params
      params.require(:model).permit?([:name, :age])
    end
```

But I get

```
Completed 400 Bad Request in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 10.3ms)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: model):
  
app/controllers/models_controller.rb:83:in `model_params'
app/controllers/models_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

#### Note

The curl request I make is

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '[{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}, {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}, {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}]' "http://localhost:3000/models"
```

Answer (score 0):

your strong param requires an object called `model` which has keys `name` and `age` so you need to make your request body in that format.

```
        { "model" : { 
                "name": "Ross", 
                "age": "25"
          }
```

but what you want is

```
    [{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}, 
{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"},
 {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}]
```

so this should work.

```
  {"model": {
    "name_and_age": [
    {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}, 
    {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"},
     {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}
    ]
    }
```

}

for this to work you'll have to change remove `:name, :age` from permit and add `name_and_age` instead somethings like.

```
def model_params
      params.require(:model).permit(:name_and_age)
    end
```

Comment: Really appreciate your response. can you please reword to use the model name (model) and attribute names (name, age) used in the question?

Comment: can you please update the question with what you're sending from front-end at the moment.. your request body.

Comment: I have updated the question to show the curl request

Comment: I tried it. I get `ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (765: unexpected token at 'model: {name_and_age: .. etc`, so I tried as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053954/testing-post-actiondispatchhttpparametersparseerror-765), now I get `Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)` and `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: model): app/controllers/models_controller.rb:83:in `model_params'` and `app/controllers/models_controller.rb:29:in `create'`

Comment: check edited answer again. and i suggest using postman instead of curl. also if you decide to go the way i'm suggesting then you'll have to process the request data in a format you want. maybe there are better ways to do it. not sure.

Answer (score 0):

possibility which I think I like even better would be to allow permit! to take an optional parameter, to allow this.

```
params.require(:model).permit(:name).permit!(:data)
```

You can refer this [This](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454)